# Filling in input box under HTML table

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login into a webpage using Python Selenium. However, I am not getting the correct response. The input box is under an HTML table in the web.

This is what I have tried after looking up some tutorials online.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input").send_keys("hi")
```

The HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>

  <form name="form" action method="post" onsubmit>
    <table border="0" , width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
    <table border="0" , width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
    <table border="0" , width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
    <table align="center" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>

    <table align="center" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr align="left">
          <td class="mandatory"> USER ID</td>
          <td class="normal">
            <input class="subject" type="text" name="username" size="35" maxlength="10" onkeypress="navigate();">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am interested to pick out the element at the `input class = "subject"`, which is the fifth table.

The following is the xPath code copied from Chrome inspector:

```
/html/body/form/table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
 //form[@name='form']/table[5]//input[@name='username']
```

[image]

You can also use the other xpath shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi supputuri, thanks for the prompt reply. However, I am hit by with this error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@name ='form']/table[5]//input[@name= 'username']"}

Comment: Are you sure you have only the html shared in OP? I am able to successfully enter the data. Check if you have any extra iframes in your application if it's different from the html that you posted in OP.

Comment: That's right, it was indeed embedded in an iframes. I only understood it after going through a few rounds of web scrapping for other webs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the login `<input>` element associated with the text **USER ID** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.subject[name='username'][onkeypress^='navigate']"))).send_keys("Wen Jiaxin")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='subject' and @name='username'][starts-with(@onkeypress, 'navigate')]"))).send_keys("Wen Jiaxin")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```